# What is the difference between the denoising autoencoder and the conventional autoencoder?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder

To train the denoising autoencoder, I constructed *x+n* in the input data and *x* in the output data(*x*: original data, *n*: noise). After learning was completed, I obtained noise-removed data through a denoising autoencoder (*x_test + n_test -> x_test*). 
Then, as a test, I trained autoencoder by constructing the input and output data to the same value, just like the conventional autoencoder
(*x* -> *x*).

As a result, i obtained noise-removed data similar to a denoising autoencoder in the test phase.
Why is noise removed through the conventional autoencoder?
Please tell me the difference between these two autoencoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An autoencoder's purpose is to map high dimensional data (e.g images) to a compressed form (i.e. hidden representation), and build up the original image from the hidden representation.

A denoising autoencoder, in addition to learning to compress data (like an autoencoder), it learns to remove noise in images, which allows to perform well even when the inputs are noisy. So denoising autoencoders are more robust than autoencoders + they learn more features from the data than a standard autoencoder.

And one of the uses of autoencoders was to find a good initialization for deep neural networks (in the late 2000s). However, with good initializations (e.g. Xavier) and activation functions (e.g. ReLU), their advantage has disappeared. Now they are more used in generative tasks (e.g. variational autoencoder)

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I now clearly understood the difference between the two autoencoders. Let me ask you one more question. Does the data compression at the training phase of the conventional autoencoder effective in removing noise in the test phase? I'd like to use the conventional autoencoder instead of a denoising autoencoder to remove noise.

Comment: I don't think a conventional autoencoder will be effective in removing noise, as they haven't been trained to remove noise. But a denoising autoencoder surely will be. Because the denoising autoencoder has been trained to do so.